# What should be image size in PWA ( Android Chrome ) compared to desktop chrome browser

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We are developing a PWA, which shows quite a few images. I've checked another website as PWA well. On chrome I could check the images size, but how to check it on Android Chrome browser?

Will the image size be same or different?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#icons) will expect two image sizes in your manifest.json:

```
icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
```

It will then take into account to scale them according to the target device. However it is good practice in order to provide the best experience, to include also pixel perfect resolutions, according to the target/expected clients devices.

From the docs:

> Success: include a 192x192 pixel icon and a 512x512 pixel icon. Chrome will automatically scale the icon for the device. If you'd prefer to scale your own icons and adjust them for pixel-perfection, provide icons in increments of 48dp.

Comment: I looked into documentation but didn't get size in KB, why is it mentioning size as 192*192 ? please clarify

Comment: The given dimensions (specified in the link to the docs) are used internally by chrome. I guess it is the logic inner in Chrome responsible for that and users do not have to worry about it. I would suggest to identify which Android versions are you targeting and then decide whether you can tailor your images specifically for those. I will search on the docs if I can find further details about the icons size (192x192 and 512x512) and post them here.